# Android recovery and reset the settings

Tags: android, reset, data-recovery

I create an application that needs to be protected from unauthorized access. I want my application to skilfully reset the factory settings.
Is there a solution to programmatically perform the recovery and reset the settings on the phone?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the question. Are you trying to reset settings for the entire phone, or just your app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a device administrator first and let the user to enable it as admin application in the settings panel.

In the new Android versions it is in Settings -> *Security* -> *Device administrators*

> Remember that you can't programmatically force the user to enable your device administrator app

Then you can use the `DevicePolicyManager` class to ask for a factory reset using this code:

```
DevicePolicyManager dpm = (DevicePolicyManager)getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
dpm.wipeData(0); //factory reset
```

You can find more info on how to create a Device Administrator app and request the correct permissions [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html)